# XSD polymorphism doesn't work with JAXP?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I had an XML like this:

```
<members>
  <member>
    <name>john</name>
    <properties>
      <age>20</age>
      <address>20</address>
   </properties>
  </member>
  <member>
    <name>kayla</name>
    <properties>
      <gender>female</gender>
      <address>20</address>
   </properties>
  </member>
</members>
```

There will be several member nodes in here, they all share a `<name>` node and a `properties` node. However, the elements in the `properties` are different, either `age+address` or `gender+address` are valid choices.

I tried to write an XSD like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="members" type="membersType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="membersType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="memberType" name="member" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="memberType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element type="propertiesType" name="properties"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="propertiesType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="address"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="propertiesTypeA">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="propertiesType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="age" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="propertiesTypeB">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="propertiesType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="gender" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

I hope there can be something like polymorphism in here, but when I validate using JAXP, that doesn't work.
I also tried to use the `group` feature, but there's a same `address` element in the 2 groups, thus it's still not available.

So, how should I design the XSD?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?  How are you doing the validation?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan The validation error indicates that the propertiesType doesn't have element ```age``` or ```gender```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your Current XML Schema

With your XML Schema the way it is, your XML would need to look like the following:

```
<members xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <member>
    <name>john</name>
    <properties xsi:type="propertiesTypeA">
      <address>20</address>
      <age>20</age>
   </properties>
  </member>
  <member>
    <name>kayla</name>
    <properties xsi:type="propertiesTypeB">
      <address>20</address>
      <gender>female</gender>
   </properties>
  </member>
</members>
```

Note the following things:

- The inherited attributes need to appear first.
- You need to use the `xsi:type` attribute to override the element type to be the subtype.

---

### What You Probably Want

Specifying a "choice" in your XML Schema would probably be a better fit for you.  You would no longer need the sub types.

```
  <xs:complexType name="propertiesType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:choice>
       <xs:element type="xs:string" name="age"/>
       <xs:element type="xs:string" name="gender"/>
      </xs:choice>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="address"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that below

```
<complexType name="MemberDTO">
        <complexContent>
            <extension base="tns:MemberEnumValueDTO">
                <sequence />
            </extension>
        </complexContent>
</complexType>

<complexType name="MemberEnumValueDTO">
        <sequence>
            <element name="name" type="tns:NameEnumTextType" minOccurs="1"
                maxOccurs="1" />
        </sequence>
</complexType>

<simpleType name="NameEnumTextType">
        <restriction base="string">
        <enumeration value="john" />
        <enumeration value="kayla" />
        </restriction>
</simpleType>
```